# How can I drag and drop files into the Ubuntu One bookmark in Nautilus?

Tags: 11.10, ubuntu-one, nautilus, drag-and-drop

I have a bookmark to my Ubuntu-One folder in the sidebar of Nautilus, it would seem logical that it would be possible to drag and drop files and folders on top of this bookmark and have the dropped items copied to the Ubuntu-One folder to be synced to the cloud. However this does not happen, I can drop files and folders onto the shortcuts underneath "Computer" in the Nautilus sidebar but not onto anything that is a bookmark.

Is it possible to change this behaviour so that it is possible? Or failing that are there any possible workarounds to get a similar result?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the update of Nautilus to version **3.4.2-0ubuntu3** it is now possible to simply drag and drop files and folders into Nautilus bookmarks. This is now possible due to the following bug being fixed: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/nautilus/+bug/874386

[image]

Answer (score 5):

You can get a similar result (where by “similar” I interpret “gives you a way to drag things into the `Ubuntu One` folder from Nautilus) in one of four ways: add an extra pane (press <kbd>F3</kbd>, or View → Extra Pane),

[image: nautilus window with no sidebar and extra pane]

switch to having a tree in the sidebar (View → Sidebar → Tree),

[image: nautilus window with sidebar tree]

add an extra tab (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>, or File → New Tab),

[image: nautilus window with no sidebar and two tabs]

or simply open a new nautilus window (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>N</kbd>, or File → New Window).

Comment: Just to note that with todays update to Nautilus, it is now possible to simply drag and drop to Ubuntu-one https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/nautilus/+bug/874386